# comparing long time value in android gives me always false in android htc phone

Tags: android

below is my code which works perfect in emulator but it doesn't work at all in htc

```
   void run()
{
 long updateStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
 long comapartime=(updateStart+30000);
        while((currentByte=stream.read())!=-1)
        {    
            bytesIn++;          

            if(System.currentTimeMillis()>=comapartime) \\always gives false in device but gives true in emulator
            {
                                    updateStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
                comapartime=(updateStart+30000);
            }
                     }
```

}

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  Seems perfectly pertinent to me.  And OP, what is `\\al`?

Comment: void run()
{
 long updateStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
 long comapartime=(updateStart+30000);
        while((currentByte=stream.read())!=-1)
        {    
            bytesIn++;          

            if(System.currentTimeMillis()>=comapartime) \\always gives here false value in HTC wildfire phone but in emulator gives true
            {
                                    updateStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
                comapartime=(updateStart+30000);
            }
                     }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void run()
{
 long updateStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
 long comapartime=(updateStart+30000);
        while((currentByte=stream.read())!=-1)
        {    
            bytesIn++;          
            long tmp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // set a break point here, is it returning 0 on device?
            if(tmp>=comapartime) \\always gives false in device but gives true in emulator
            {
                                    updateStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
                comapartime=(updateStart+30000);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks jack for reply .i tried this it gives me proper current time.could you plz suggest any other way.i want to check the downloaded bytes at each 30secs intervals.i have started one activity which has a button to start the thread which contains above logic.

Comment: Ok do the same for compartime, what is its value on the actual device?

Comment: thanks again for your reply.it calls the while loop only once as per the log (i got the value only one)and i could not debug using htc device as it is not connect to pc.

Comment: How you get the program onto the HTC? You should be able to debug by leaving the USB plugged in after hitting debug.